# POST requests using HTTR

Tags: r

I'm struggling to write a httr:POST statement equivalent to the following curl command (actual client_id & client_secret replaced by dummy strings):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "ContentType: x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 
"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXX" 
"https://api.beta.tab.com.au/oauth/token"
```

I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
POST("https://api.beta.tab.com.au/oauth/token",
  add_headers('Content-Type'='application/json'),
  body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials",
  client_id = "XXXXXXXX",
  client_secret = "XXXXXXXX"),
  encode = "json")
```

I expect the resulting status code to be 200, but this hasn't been the case...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `curl` command above is working. When checking the definition of `curl -d` [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), one can see that the data is passed to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. However you are building your post command with json encoding. I other words, you are not sending the same format in your POST body and I am assuming this is your issue here as it is probable your server is expecting the data in **form urlencoded** and not in **json**. You should check this [quickstart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html#request-body) and try running your command in an interactive session with the verbose flag set to see what is being sent to the server.